# Turning list of integers into string in OCaml

Tags: list, int, ocaml, fold

How could I turn a list of integers, such as [1;2;3], into a single string "123" using fold?

Right now, I think I'm doing:

```
let int_list_to_string (s : int list) : string =
  fold (fun s combine -> combine + .... ) ""
```

or something along these lines, where .... could be something similar to String.length (which I used in a different fold problem to count characters in a string) but I don't know if this is even remotely correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic layout looks right to me. Many things need to be fixed up. Here are a few:

1. You have to pick a specific fold function to use, `List.fold_left` or `List.fold_right`.
2. The function to be folded takes two parameters. One is the accumulated result and the other is the next input from the list. The order depends on whether you use `fold_left` or `fold_right`. Your code sketch has two parameters but one of them is suspiciously named `s`. This will not be the same `s` as the input list. The names after `fun` are new parameter variables introduced at that point.
3. The OCaml operator for concatenating strings is `^`, which is what you should use where you have `+` (possibly just a placeholder in your code).
4. You need to convert each int to a string before concatenating. There is a function named `string_of_int` that does this.
5. You have to apply the fold to a list. I.e., fold takes 3 arguments but you are supplying only 2 arguments in your code sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `fun` needs to concatenate an `acc` and the next list-element with the `^` - operator. The accumulator of `List.fold_left` needs to be the same as the output type, so it has to be an empty string:  `""`.

```
let int_list_to_string lst = List.fold_left (fun acc x -> acc ^ string_of_int x) "" lst
val int_list_to_string : int list -> string = <fun>

# int_list_to_string [1;2;3];;
- : string = "123"
```

One could also create more advanced strings, e.g. with the `list`-syntax:

```
let int_list_to_string_fancy lst =
   "[" ^ ( List.fold_left( fun acc x -> acc ^ string_of_int x ^ ";" ) "" lst) ^ "]"
val int_list_to_string_fancy : int list -> string = <fun>

# int_list_to_string_fancy [1;2;3];;
- : string = "[1;2;3;]"
```

Comment: There's no need to answer to what looks like a homework question with a direct answer (give a fish, learn to fish...) even more when another answer has already been accepted. You're new to StackOverflow so I'm trying to help here.